# Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement. Semicolon already exists

Tags: sql, vb.net, where-clause, insert-into, oledbcommand

I keep getting this error `Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.` when I run this code:

```
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Tickers (Quarter_Balance_Sheets) VALUES (Scrapalbe) WHERE Ticker = A;", con)
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited..

Sorry. After reading again you cannot use WHERE on an INSERT statement, loose the WHERE clause or make an UPDATE statement.

INSERT INTO ... WHERE is not a valid query.

If the insert you've posted has correct values and columns, the update should be:

```
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Tickers SET Quarter_Balance_Sheets = 'Scrapalbe' WHERE Ticker = 'A';", con)
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: What would the UPDATE statement look like?

Comment: Thanks. First think if you need an insert or an update. Then write the query.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 3):

Missing quotes `WHERE Ticker = 'A'` and in `VALUES ('Scrapalbe')`

edit: @Engerlost is right, `where` is not applicable to `insert`; you still need quotes but drop `where...` completely

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got the same error. `Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.`

Comment: @LarsTech I'm using Microsoft Access.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @EricPetroelje I still get the same error when I try `WHERE Ticker = 'A'` and in `VALUES ('Scrapalbe')`

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your query is you're using where in your insert statement.

the query is,

```
insert into Tablename (val1, val2, ...) values(val1, val2,....)
```